# Game CPU and GPU with synchronized latency on Unreal Engine

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am running an Unreal Engine scene through NDisplay and while investigating the cause for very low FPS, I came across this behaviour that I've never seen before:
I brought up the stats with stat unit and stat fps command and the Game and GPU values are almost identical and their behaviour looks entangled as it fluctuates at the same rate (see pictures here [IMAGES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNbRS.jpg)).

This is making it extra difficult to profile what's going on, I've never seen this behaviour before.

Any clarification or indication could really help, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had several issues with nDisplay and refresh rate problems, it's hard to guess what's wrong in your case. Can you specify what GPUs you are using, how many over how many PCs, at what resolution and if in stereo mode or mono? (do so by editing your original post)

Did you try to activate VSync (either in UE4 or in your GPU control panel)? Also try to disable AntiAliasing in the UE4 project settings. What else... in UE4 editor change the way you display the scene from "Lit" to "Optimization viewmodes->Light Density", your lightmaps could be too high res (in which case your scene will look all red). You can also try to display the shader's complexity ("Optimization viewmodes->Shader complexity") and see if there's some specific part of the scene that is "too heavy". I had such a problem with particles and fire, when multiple flames were on one screen but not the other the fps wasn't coherent for the two screen and caused a lot of sync issues.

You can also try changing the UE4 project setting Max FPS: cap it to your screen's refresh rate (and set constant FPS); or set not constant FPS and set min and max FPS values to what you'd like.

More in general, problems with nDisplay tend not to show the symptoms you would expect on a "simple" system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I "solved" in the sense that I don't have the issue anymore but I have no idea what was causing it. We have removed one of the 7 viewports, extended the 6th to cover the portion that was occupied by the 7th and everything just started going smooth and with no issues whatsoever. Again, no idea what happened but it works